# Make R stopifnot or similar simple function raise an error when expression returns length of zero

Tags: r, validation, error-handling

I'm using the `stopifnot` function in R to validate an expected result.  However, I've noticed that if the expression returns a vector of length 0, then `stopifnot` will not raise an error.  Here is a simple reproducible example.

Imagine an optimization function where one of the list elements is named `convergence` containing either a 0 or 1, and I wish to validate that the element named `convergence` contains 0 and raise an error otherwise.

```
return01 <- function(x){
    return(list(convergence = x))
}
opt1 <- return01(1)
```

I can easily do the validation I desire with `stopifnot`.

```
stopifnot(opt1$convergence == 0) # raises desired error
```

However, imagine I typed the wrong element name such as `converged` instead of `convergence`.  My validation no longer throws any error because `opt1$converged` is `NULL` and `opt1$converged == 0` resolves to `logical(0)`

```
stopifnot(opt1$converged == 0) # does not raise an error
stopifnot(NULL == 0) # does not raise an error
```

I've come up the workaround below where I would always have to also validate the length of the expression as well.

```
stopifnot(opt1$converged == 0, length(opt1$converged == 0) > 0) # raises an error
stopifnot(NULL == 0, length(NULL == 0) > 0) # raises an error
```

Is there a simpler, more elegant, or better practice solution here to make this validation robust to the expression returning `logical(0)` yet retaining the simplicity and conciseness of `stopifnot(opt1$convergence == 0)` rather than having to explicitly do another expression using `length`?  Specifically, I would like the validation to also raise an error if the expression returns `logical(0)`.

Comment: `stopifnot(!is.null(NULL))`

Comment: @alistaire thanks.  It appears what I really meant to ask was if the expression returns `logical(0)` how to still raise an error in elegant and concise way without having to explicitly check the length of the expression.  I've revised the question to more accurately reflect this.

Comment: you could also use `!length(x)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico thanks, looks like `stopifnot(length(NULL == 0))` would do the trick and is better than my workaround.

Comment: If still relevant, [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/stopifnot-with-logical-0-td4715435.html) there is quite a lengthy discussion on `stopinfnot` and `logical(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether it is identical to zero:

```
stopifnot(identical(opt1$convergence, 0))
```

or if convergence is normally of integer type use `0L`.

The code above will raise an error if convergence is anything other than 0. For example,

```
stopifnot(identical(1, 0))
## Error: identical(1, 0) is not TRUE

stopifnot(identical(NULL, 0))
## Error: identical(NULL, 0) is not TRUE

stopifnot(identical(numeric(0), 0)
## Error: identical(numeric(0), 0) is not TRUE

stopifnot(identical(logical(0), 0))
## Error: identical(logical(0), 0) is not TRUE
```